# PHP POST Array issues

Tags: php, post

Building a page that displays a list of available items which a checkbox to select item and a text box to specify quantity of the desired item.

When I submit what I have, the item id (which is specified by the checkbox input) is passed with no problems, but the quantity field is not. What am I doing wrong.

This is the form script

```
<?php       
while($is_data = mysql_fetch_array($get_it_sp))
{                       
$it_sp_id = $is_data['it_sp_id'];
$it_sp_Name = $is_data['it_sp_Name'];
$it_sp_HirePrice = $is_data['it_sp_hirePrice'];

echo "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='qu_li_it_it_sp_id[]' value='".$it_sp_id."' /></td>";
echo "<td>".$it_sp_Name."</td><td>".$it_sp_HirePrice."</td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='qu_li_it_Quantity[]' /></td></tr>";
}
?>
```

This is the handler

```
if(!empty($_POST['qu_li_it_it_sp_id']))
{
    for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['qu_li_it_it_sp_id']); $i++)
    {
        if(!empty($_POST['qu_li_it_it_sp_id'][$i]))
        {
            $qu_li_it_it_sp_id = $_POST['qu_li_it_it_sp_id'][$i];
        }


        if(!empty($_POST['qu_li_it_Quantity'][$i]))
        {
            $qu_li_it_Quantity = $_POST['qu_li_it_Quantity'][$i];
            echo $qu_li_it_Quantity;
        }

        $get_hire_price = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM itemspec WHERE it_sp_id = '$qu_li_it_it_sp_id'")

        while($hi_data = mysql_fetch_array($get_hire_price))
        {
            $it_sp_HirePrice = $hi_data['it_sp_hirePrice'];

            $qu_li_it_SubTotal = $qu_li_it_Quantity * $it_sp_HirePrice;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm kinda new to this so be gentle.

Comment: try changing `echo "<td><input type='text' name='qu_li_it_Quantity[]' /></td></tr>";` to `echo "<td><input type='text' name='qu_li_it_Quantity[]' value='' /></td></tr>";`

Comment: Yeah I tried that as well before I posted the question. I think it has something to do with the array. When i check the first two boxes in the list it works perfectly. But if I select two random boxes only the checkbox value is passed correctly